# geoserver/openlayers: multiple layer geotiff

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, layers

I have a geotiff file with multiple layers (46 layers), each layer corresponding to a different date (the geotiff layers corresponding to sea surface temperature, 1 layer per year).

I imported this geotiff in geoserver, but I can't render it with the geoserver visualisation tool (based on openlayers).

1./ does geoserver support multiple layers > 3 bands?
2./ if yes, when I query the WMS in openlayers, how can I select a given layer?

Comment: Can you say how your layers are named (if any)? Specifically, what is the relationship between the name and the date?